# how to Open New class from javascript page using android phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, native-code

I'm using `phonegap` and i cant extend it to activity for the class intiating so i need to extend it to `droidgap` only but i want one button should keep in the page to move on to next class where i can extend `activity` and perform layout and other properties .

Here either i need to call from native `javascript` function or need to call intent for the next class in `java android` file only .

If any one knows this issue please answer.

Comment: Where do you perform your layout? In different class?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Next class will extend to activity and perform the layout operations and functions. so that i need to know how to get here to next class because in previous class we hv to extend to droidgap cant add setcontentView or any button.

Comment: @Coder_sLaY When loadurl page works over then i need to get out of the page by one click in page to other page [cameraupload](https://github.com/brycecurtis/articles/tree/master/CameraUpload).check out here when i upload pic to server after that i want a button to move me to next page where i can write different code or extend activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your First class extending DroidGap, will navigate to index.html page
Then from JavaScript you can call another class & perform anything by creating an android plugin like given in the [phonegap wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android)

Let me know if you have other doubts.